# String encoding conversion UTF-8 to SHIFT-JIS

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Variables used:

- JavaSE-6
- No frameworks

---

Given this string input of `ピーター・ジョーズ` which is encoded in **UTF-8**, I am having problems converting the said string to **Shift-JIS** without the need of writing the said data to a file.

- Input (UTF-8 encoding): `ピーター・ジョーンズ`
- Output (SHIFT-JIS encoding): `ピーター・ジョーンズ` (SHIFT-JIS to be encoded)

---

I've tried this code snippets on how to convert UTF-8 strings to SHIFT-JIS:

- `stringToEncode.getBytes(Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS"))`
- `new String(unecodedString.getBytes("SHIFT-JIS"), "UTF-8")`

Both code snippets return this string output: `�s�[�^�[�E�W���[���Y` (SHIFT-JIS encoded)

Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341853/string-encoding-shift-jis-utf-8

Comment: I don't get the whole picture. `String`s in java are always encoded in UTF-16, any other encoding is either held in a byte-array or written to some kind of file/console/.... So from where do you get your input and where do you write/view your output?

Comment: What do you mean by "converting without writing to a file"? Where do you want the Shift-JIS to go?

Comment: @piyushjaiswal the suggestion is already listed above, and it produced unexpected output of `�s�[�^�[�E�W���[���Y`.

Comment: @piet.t the Shift-JIS output needs to be fetched as a string on a web service actually.

Comment: @Thilo the Shift-JIS output needs to be fetched as a string on a web service actually.

Comment: `stringToEncode.getBytes(Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS"))` will almost certainly return the correct Shift-JIS bytes. What do you do with them next? How are you sending them out from your web service ?

Comment: @CyrilHorad: Please show more code. It should include where the data is coming from before the conversion and where it is going to.

Answer (score 3):

Internally in Java, Strings are implemented as an array of UTF-16 code units. But this is an implementation detail, it would be possible to implement a JVM that uses a different encoding internally.

(Note "encoding", "charset" and Charset are more or less synonyms.)

A String should be treated as a sequence of Unicode codepoints (even though in Java it's a sequence of UTF-16 code units).

If you have a String in your Java program, it is *incorrect* to say that it is a "UTF-8 String" or "String which is encoded in UTF-8". That does not make any sense, unless you're talking about the internal representation, which is irrelevant.

What you can have is a sequence of bytes that decode to a String if you decode it using an encoding, such as UTF-8 or Shift-JIS.

Or you can have a String that encodes to a sequence of bytes if you encode it using an encoding, such as UTF-8 or Shift-JIS.

In short, an encoding or Charset is a pair of two functions, "encode" and "decode" such that:

```
// String -> encode -> bytes
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(encoding);
// or using Charset
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = charset.encode(string);

// bytes -> decode -> String
String string = new String(bytes, encoding);
// or using Charset
String string = charset.decode(byteBuffer).toString();
```

So if you have a byte[] that's encoded using UTF-8:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = "ピーター・ジョーズ".getBytes("UTF-8");
// utf8Bytes now contains, in hexadecimal
// e3 83 94  e3 83 bc  e3 82 bf   (ピ ー タ)
// e3 83 bc  e3 83 bb  e3 82 b8   (ー ・ ジ)
// e3 83 a7  e3 83 bc  e3 82 ba   (ョ ー ズ)
```

You can create a String from those bytes using:

```
String string = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");
// String now contains "ピーター・ジョーズ"
```

Then you can encode that String as Shift-JIS using:

```
byte[] shiftJisBytes = string.getBytes("Shift-JIS");
// shiftJisBytes now contains, in hexadecimal
// 83 73  81 5b  83 5e   (ピ ー タ)
// 81 5b  81 45  83 57   (ー ・ ジ)
// 83 87  81 5b  83 59   (ョ ー ズ)
```

Since those bytes represent a string encoded using `Shift-JIS`, trying to decode using `UTF-8` will produce garbage:

```
String garbage = new String(shiftJisBytes, "UTF-8")
// String now contains "�s�[�^�[�E�W���[�Y"
// � is the character decoded when given an invalid UTF-8 sequence
// 83 73 81 5b 83 5e   (� s � [ � ^)
// 81 5b 81 45 83 57   (� [ � E � W)
// 83 87 81 5b 83 59   (� � � [ � Y)
```

Further, remember that if you print a string to an output, for example `System.out`, that will use the system default encoding that is system dependent to convert the String to bytes. It looks like your system default is `UTF-8`.

```
System.out.print(string);
// equivalent to:
System.out.write(string.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

Then if your output is for example the Windows console, it will then convert those bytes to a String using very probably a completely different encoding (probably `CP437` or `CP850`) before presenting it to you.

This last part might be tripping you up.

Answer (score 0):

"MS932" instead of Shift-JIS/SJIS may make it.