# Japanese character change to junk after writing to file in java

Tags: java, file, utf-8, character-encoding, inputstreamreader

Japanese character display the actual content when I read through the inputStreamReader object(only specifying the encoded charset), however when I check on the output of the physical file, it contains 
junk character.
I have a below questions, please help me out to understand.

1. Why physical file change to junk?   e.g:¥Ô¡¼¥¿¡¼¡¦¥¸¥ç¡¼¥º opened with notepad.    Note:    Same when I open on OpenOffice Calc
   setting charset it displays actual     Japanese character.
2. While reading using inputStreamReader if I specify other than
   encoded character,actual content change to junk.
   e.g:�ԡ����������硼��   So as per my understanding encoded charset and
   decoded charset must be the same.*

I have checked this answer, [String encoding conversion UTF-8 to SHIFT-JIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155417/string-encoding-conversion-utf-8-to-shift-jis).

But what I need to know is suppose encoded file is different while decoding 
if we use UTF-8 does is it possible display the actual content.

```
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("japanese.txt");
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "EUC-JP");
    osw.write("ピーター・ジョーズ");
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();

    InputStream ir = new FileInputStream("japanese.txt");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ir, "EUC-JP");
    int i =isr.read();
    while(i!=-1) {
        System.out.print((char)i);
        i=isr.read();
    }
    isr.close();
```

encoding & decoding - (EUC-JP)

```
ピーター・ジョーズ
```

encoding - EUC-JP  : decoding - UTF-8

```
�ԡ����������硼��
```

Comment: When you print the text out, it is possible that your screen / OS simply doesn't have the character's installed to display them, so you just get the "I dunno what this is" character instead.  (Otherwise, your code looks OK at first glance, so I suspect the problem is elsewhere, i.e. possibly your display.)

Comment: Wait, you're asking if you *encode* the file as EUC-JP, then *decode* it as UTF-8, will that work?  NO, it won't work, it's obviously broken AF.  Why would you even try that?

Comment: @markspace ok thanks for your response. So mean here editor is the problem? can you clarify my 2nd question?

Comment: Ok well.
I am just trying is there any way to decode, that's all.

Comment: The only way to decode is to use the same decoding as it was encoded with.  If you want to read UTF-8, in the first part, *write out* the file with UTF-8, not EUC-JP.

Comment: Notepad assumes a one-byte character set such as windows-1252 (unless the file starts with a Byte Order Mark character);  it doesn’t know that your file’s bytes are actually characters encoded in EUC-JP.  `ピ` is represented in EUC-JP as the two bytes 0xa5 0xd4, but Notepad assumes those two bytes represent two single-byte characters from windows-1252, specifically [U+00A5 YEN SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a5/) (`¥`) and [U+00D4 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d4/) (`Ô`).