# Encoding issue with Japanese text in HTML

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, cjk, shift-jis

I am working with an old Japanese Website Project. I download the old files from the server and it's working fine in offline mode with browser.

But when I open it with editor the text is broken. Then I try to fix this problem by changing the encoding to most of them. like below.

- utf-8
- utf-8 with bom
- Shift JIS
- etc

Then I try it with several modern editors and by changing meta charset. Also I tried to find a solution on google but I got nothing positive.

Only HTML Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
  <meta name="keywords" content="�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽ,�ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ,�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ\,�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ,,�ｿｽp�ｿｽ鼬暦ｿｽﾌ外�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽl�ｿｽl�ｿｽﾞ派�ｿｽ�ｿｽ">
  <meta name="description" content="�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾌ翻�ｿｽ�ｿｽE�ｿｽﾊ厄ｿｽﾍビ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽR�ｿｽX�ｿｽI�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽl�ｿｽC�ｿｽe�ｿｽB�ｿｽu�ｿｽﾉゑｿｽ�ｿｽm�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾈテ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽB�ｿｽr�ｿｽW�ｿｽl�ｿｽX�ｿｽA�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽI�ｿｽE�ｿｽZ�ｿｽp�ｿｽI�ｿｽﾈ難ｿｽe�ｿｽﾌテ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾜで包ｿｽ�ｿｽL�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾅのテ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽs�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾄゑｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB">
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <title>�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽ �ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ\</title>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0 var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array(); var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments;
    for(i=0; i
    <a.length; i++) if (a[i].indexOf( "#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}} } function MM_swapImgRestore() {
    //v3.0 var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc; } function MM_findObj(n,
      d) { //v4.01 var p,i,x; if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf( "?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) { d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);} if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n];
      for (i=0;!x&&i
      <d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n]; for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
        if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x; } function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0 var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments;
        document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3) if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc)
        x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];} } function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0 eval(targ+ ".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+
        "'"); if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0; } </script>
        <link href="../../../styleseet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="bodycss" id="02">
  <table class="top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <table class="top_text" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              �ｿｽ@�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽ|�ｿｽ�ｿｽ �ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾊ厄ｿｽ �ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾌネ�ｿｽC�ｿｽe�ｿｽB�ｿｽu�ｿｽX�ｿｽ^�ｿｽb�ｿｽt�ｿｽ|�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾒにゑｿｽ�ｿｽT�ｿｽ|�ｿｽ[�ｿｽg
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="790" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <table class="sub_bg" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
              <a href="/">
                <img src="../../img/spacer.gif" width="197" height="47" alt="�ｿｽr�ｿｽ[�ｿｽR�ｿｽX" border="0">
              </a>
            </td>
            <td class="top_Navi">
              <ul>
                <li class="gnv01">
                  <a href="/">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ{�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>
                </li>
                <li class="gnv02">
                  <a href="/english/">english</a>
                </li>
                <li class="gnv03">
                  <a href="/chinese/">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>
                </li>
                <li class="gnv04">
                  <a href="/korean/">�ｿｽﾘ搾ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="35" align="right">
              <table class="ken" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td class="ken_bg">�ｿｽT�ｿｽC�ｿｽg�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type=text name=q maxlength=255 class="ken_input">
                  </td>
                  <td width="50">
                    <input type=submit name=btnG value="�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ" class="ken_btn">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="sub_bg02" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="sub_tdregi">
              <table class="sub_regi" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td class="title">�ｿｽo�ｿｽ^�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</td>
                  <td class="con">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/country.js"></script>
                    �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="title">�ｿｽo�ｿｽ^�ｿｽl�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</td>
                  <td class="con">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/people.js"></script>
                    �ｿｽl</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="title">�ｿｽo�ｿｽ^�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ齔�</td>
                  <td class="con">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/language.js"></script>
                    �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td class="text999">�ｿｽr�ｿｽ[�ｿｽR�ｿｽX�ｿｽﾅは外�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽl�ｿｽl�ｿｽb�ｿｽg�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽA�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾈゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾆ撰ｿｽ�ｿｽE�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾂなゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="down_Navi">
          <ul>
            <li class="gn01">
              <a href="/">�ｿｽz�ｿｽ[�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="gn02">
              <a href="../../01language/">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ闊ｵ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="gn03">
              <a href="../../02foreigner/">�ｿｽO�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽl�ｿｽh�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽT�ｿｽ[�ｿｽr�ｿｽX</a>
            </li>
            <li class="gn04">
              <a href="../../03business/">�ｿｽC�ｿｽO�ｿｽr�ｿｽW�ｿｽl�ｿｽX�ｿｽT�ｿｽ|�ｿｽ[�ｿｽg</a>
            </li>
            <li class="gn05">
              <a href="../../04international/">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾛ交流奇ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="gn06">
              <a href="../../05staff/">�ｿｽX�ｿｽ^�ｿｽb�ｿｽt�ｿｽo�ｿｽ^</a>
            </li>
            <li class="gn07">
              <a href="../../06price/">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ齬暦ｿｽ\</a>
            </li>
            <li class="gn08">
              <a href="../../07estimate/">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾏゑｿｽﾋ暦ｿｽ</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px #000 solid;">
          <tr>
            <td width="140" valign="top" bgcolor="#42418c">
              <!--#include Virtual="../left-->
            </td>
            <td width="641" valign="top">
              <br>
              <table width="630" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="f12">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="/">TOP</a>�ｿｽ�ｿｽ
                    <a href="../../">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ闊ｵ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>�ｿｽ�ｿｽ
                    <a href="../">�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>�ｿｽ�ｿｽ
                    <a href="../../14tape/">�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</a>�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ\
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center ">
                  <td>
                    <br>
                    <a href="/ ">�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽs�ｿｽn�ｿｽo</a> |
                    <a href="#garuntee ">�ｿｽi�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾛ擾ｿｽ</a>
                    |
                    <a href="price>�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ\</a> |
                    <a href=" estimation>�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾏゑｿｽ</a>
                    |
                    <a href=" ../ ">�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽT�ｿｽ[�ｿｽr�ｿｽX�ｿｽ齬�</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center ">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <font color="#000000 " size="3 ">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ\
                      <br>
                    </font>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center ">
                    <table width="95% " border="0 " cellspacing="5 " cellpadding="0 " bgcolor="#CCCCCC
                      " height="200 ">
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF " valign="top ">
                          <div align="left ">
                            <table border="0 " width="100% " cellspacing="3 ">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="49% ">
                                  <div align="center ">
                                    <center>
                                      <table border="1 " width="300 " cellspacing="0 " bordercolor="#000080
                      " bordercolordark="#000080 " bordercolorlight="#000080 ">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td width="293 " align="center ">
                                            <p align="center ">�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ\</p>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center ">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ600/1�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table>
                                    </center>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <table width="300 " border="1 " align="center " cellspacing="0 " bordercolor="#000080
                      " bordercolorlight="#000080 " bordercolordark="#000080 ">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="294 " align="center ">
                                        <p align="center ">�ｿｽp�ｿｽ�ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽN�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ+�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ{�ｿｽ�ｿｽｿ具ｿｽ\</p>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center ">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ2,500/1�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽl�ｿｽF
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾔゑｿｽm�ｿｽF�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾌ鯉ｿｽ�ｿｽﾏゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾆなゑｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB&nbsp;
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾍ通擾ｿｽA�ｿｽc�ｿｽﾆ難ｿｽ3�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾈ擾ｿｽﾆなゑｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽX�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾉゑｿｽ�ｿｽe�ｿｽ[�ｿｽv�ｿｽﾌ受け渡�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾌ場合�ｿｽﾍ郵�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾉ会ｿｽ�ｿｽZ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽi�ｿｽﾍ��ｿｽ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽh�ｿｽf�ｿｽ[�ｿｽ^�ｿｽ[�ｿｽi�ｿｽﾆなゑｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾅ低注�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽi3,000�ｿｽ~�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾆなゑｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾋ暦ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽe�ｿｽﾉ関ゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾄキ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽZ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ鼾��ｿｽﾍ、�ｿｽL�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽZ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽｸゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾅは別途�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾆなゑｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB&nbsp;
                                  <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾈ擾ｿｽﾔなゑｿｽﾌに関ゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾄは以会ｿｽ�ｿｽﾌ表�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽB&nbsp;
                                  <tr>
                                    <TD>
                                      <TABLE width="100% " border=1 cellspacing="0 " bordercolor="#000080 " cellpadding="2
                      " bordercolorlight="#000080 " bordercolordark="#000080 ">
                                        <TBODY>
                                          <TR>
                                            <TD width="164 ">
                                              <DIV align="center">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</DIV> </TD>
                                            <TD width="221 ">
                                              <DIV align="center">�ｿｽ�ｿｽe</DIV>
                                            </TD>
                                            <TD width="165 ">
                                              <DIV align="center">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</DIV>
                                            </TD>
                                          </TR>
                                          <TR>
                                            <TD width="164 ">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ蜷ｫ�ｿｽﾌ搾ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</TD>
                                            <TD width="221 ">�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾃ関連�ｿｽﾈど撰ｿｽ蜷ｫ�ｿｽﾌ搾ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ </TD>
                                            <TD width="165 ">25�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ`50�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ </TD>
                                          </TR>
                                          <TR>
                                            <TD width="164 ">�ｿｽﾌ趣ｿｽ�ｿｽA�ｿｽj�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽX�ｿｽﾈゑｿｽ</TD>
                                            <TD width="221 ">�ｿｽﾌの歌趣ｿｽ�ｿｽA�ｿｽ�ｿｽb�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽx�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾌゑｿｽﾈゑｿｽ </TD>
                                            <TD width="165 ">100�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ </TD>
                                          </TR>
                                          <TR>
                                            <TD width="164 ">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ}</TD>
                                            <TD width="221 ">�ｿｽS�ｿｽ`�ｿｽT�ｿｽc�ｿｽﾆ難ｿｽ�ｿｽﾈ難ｿｽ </TD>
                                            <TD width="165 ">50�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ </TD>
                                          </TR>
                                          <TR>
                                            <TD width="164 ">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ}</TD>
                                            <TD width="221 ">�ｿｽP�ｿｽ`�ｿｽR�ｿｽc�ｿｽﾆ難ｿｽ�ｿｽﾈ難ｿｽ </TD>
                                            <TD width="165 ">100�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ </TD>
                                          </TR>
                                          <TR>
                                            <TD width="164 ">�ｿｽ^�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾔゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾇゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾈゑｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾌ（�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽj</TD>
                                            <TD width="221 ">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾉゑｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ </TD>
                                            <TD width="165 ">25�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ`50�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ </TD>
                                          </TR>
                                        </TBODY>
                                      </TABLE>
                                    </TD>
                                    <tr>
                                      <TD> �ｿｽi�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽj�ｿｽﾇゑｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾄゑｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾈゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾓ擾ｿｽ�ｿｽﾉ関ゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾄは×�ｿｽ~�ｿｽ~�ｿｽﾆ表�ｿｽL�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ鼾��ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾜゑｿｽ�ｿｽB
                                        <br>
                                        <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾏゑｿｽﾉ関ゑｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ
                                        <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾏ対会ｿｽ�ｿｽi1�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾔ以難ｿｽj�ｿｽA�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾏ厄ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ
                                        <br> �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ{�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ[�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽf�ｿｽB�ｿｽX�ｿｽJ�ｿｽE�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽg�ｿｽﾉ関ゑｿｽ�ｿｽﾄはゑｿｽ�ｿｽ竝��ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽB
                                        </TD>
                                    </TR>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
              </table>
              <br>
              <table width="600 " border="0 " align="center " cellspacing="0 ">
                <tr>
                  <td height="20 "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center ">
                    <!--#include Virtual="../foot_price-->
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <br>
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                  <table width="100%" class="footer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <th width="397" height="50" class="text_no">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾏゑｿｽE�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ竄｢�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ墲ｹ�ｿｽﾍ気�ｿｽy�ｿｽﾉどゑｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ</th>
                      <td width="395">
                        <a href="/01language/estimateall><img src=" ../../img/spacer.gif " width="131 " height="68 " alt="�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽﾏゑｿｽ "></a> 
                <a href="/02foreigner/inquiry-for-dispatch>
                          <img src="../../img/spacer.gif" width="125" height="68" alt="�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ竝��ｿｽ�ｿｽ">
                        </a>
                        <a href="/06price/">
                          <img src="../../img/spacer.gif" width="121" height="68" alt="�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ\">
                        </a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="50" colspan="2" class="footer_text">�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ �ｿｽﾐ　�ｿｽ�ｿｽ105-0013�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽs�ｿｽ`�ｿｽ�ｿｽl�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ2-1-3 �ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽX�ｿｽr�ｿｽ�ｿｽ4F
                        Tel�ｿｽF03-5733-4264 Fax�ｿｽF03-3433-3320
                        <br /> Copyright &copy; by b-cause,Inc. 2003-2016 </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Editor Screenshot with encoding problem]

Comment: can you post the code? or at least a small sample, like of the title element?

Comment: HTML code added, please check

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341853/string-encoding-shift-jis-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

All the Japanese content in the HTML seems completely broken.

I have tried to decode the (garbled) strings in various encoding with [ひたすらデコード](https://so-zou.jp/web-app/text/encode-decode/hitasura/), but all the result doesn't seem meaningful strings.

Maybe the HTML file is wrongly transformed and saved when you open the file with the editor. The reliable way to recover the content is downloading the HTML file from the server again, and then open the file with another editor that can handle Japanese encoding like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).